# Why Laravel throw_unless giving internal server error?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel `throw_unless` in my code. It works fine in local PC, but in production server it always throw "Server Error".

```
    throw_unless($product->unit_price > 1, OutOfStockException::class,'Product out of stock!');
```

and exception class:

```
class OutOfStockException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($message = "")
    {
        parent::__construct($message);
    }

    public function report() {
        \Log::debug('Product out of stock');
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "Server Error" it means OutOfStockException? Or it's some other exception that can potentially indicate you have an error in condition or smth.

Comment: No. If i pass `false` then getting same exception.

Comment: Any more details you can provide other than just "Server error"? What's in your logs?

Comment: Not sure you understand how this function works. Cause "false" value is a trigger to throw an exception in throw_unless. https://laravel-news.com/throw_if-throw_unless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing my Exception class it's working.

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use App\Core\Exceptions\RenderAble;

class OutOfStockException extends Exception
{
    use RenderAble;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $this->message = $message
        );
    }
}
```